# Can't embed glut files in c# setup project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, opengl

I have built a project for learning OpenGL in Visual Studio 2010. When I run the program from my pc everything works ok. I also built a setup proj for this application. When I run the .msi in a computer that has not visual studio and try to run my embedded opengl examples, it says that cannot find glu files.

My glut files are extracted from a zip file in "C:/examples/GL" and I have updated my linker props for all my examples.

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Does "it says that cannot find glu files" mean that a dll is missing? If so, your problem is, that the path where you copied the files to is not in the library search path.

Comment: The dll file.. but the path is ok! The embedded examples works fine. Only when I run the app in a pc with no visual studio have problem

Comment: According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx), there is no simply no possibility to tell windows to look at C:/examples/GL for your dlls. (unless you add this directory to the PATH environment variable).

Comment: I did this.. The path environment variable is OK